# Is it possible to control refresh rate/frequency of Android phones camera

Tags: camera, hardware, video-recording

I recorded a video of my TV screen using my android phone's camera but I was unable to stop the flickering TV screen. I tried different modes and effects in the camera app. 
On searching for the reason I found in this [Superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/663032/monitor-is-flashing-through-camera-but-not-in-the-naked-eye/663052) that the reason for this is difference in refresh frequencies of the TV screen and the camera. 
So is their any way by which I may adjust the frequency of my phone's camera?